# When working with polyurethane glue, how long does one have to clamp the components?

Tags: glue, polyurethane

I am going to be building some shutters for one of our windows and because of its location, planned on using polyurethane glue, specifically Dap Polyurethane Construction Adhesive. Each shutter will be made of four five-inch boards, dowelled and glued together. They will be clamped in two dimensions, one to compress the individual boards together and the other to keep the shutter flat. Each of the shutters is 76½ inches long and twenty inches wide.
Once the glue is applied to the boards, dowels, and holes, the clamping process will probably take several minutes. How much time do I have to get everything together before the glues is too dry?
**Edit:** I am planning on using five clamps to hold the boards together and two to keep the whole thing flat.
**Edit 2:** The boards are pressure treated.

Comment: This is the stuff in a rigid plastic tube, dispensed with a caulking gun correct? If so wrong thing for this application. Construction adhesives aren't really suitable as wooden joinery adhesives because they're so thick. Assuming your joinery is well cut (tight joints) you'd actually be better off using standard polyurethane glue, e.g. the original Gorilla glue.

Comment: @Graphus, these shutters are going to be installed on a side of our house that gets full afternoon sun and the brunt of winter storms. As far as I could tell this stuff was the best for this application. I have a table saw on which to cut the boards, so the joints should be tight.

Comment: This basically isn't a woodworking adhesive. The product description and relevant data make it clear it's intended for flashing etc. Any standard adhesive sold for exterior use would be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a more general answer, all glues will include directions/instructions which will specify the working/open time (how long you have to get everything aligned and clamped), the amount of time to remain clamped and a full cure time.

These times are approximates as temperature and humidity can play a role in the overall time, so assume the times given are for average temperatures and humidity values.  Usually warmer temperatures mean faster cure times.

You should pick a glue that has appropriate times for your specific project needs.

Comment: I read the instruction on the tube and don't see anything about working time.

Comment: If not on the label them a quick google turns up http://www.dap.com/media/73592/polyurethane-sealants.pdf.   "Product is tack free in 3-6 hours and will achieve full cure in 4-7 days, depending on joint depth,
temperature and humidity. "

Comment: I too found that same PDF, but unless I'm totally blind, I don't find anything in it that specifies open time. There's some stuff about tack-free time and cure but nothing about how quickly one's work has to be clamped.

Comment: @BillOertell it's not glue, it's construction adhesive...